# Working with bezier curve, I need to fill the hole at the end

Tags: bezier-curves

I made a rope using a bezier curve.  I then proceeded to use the bevel option to have a rope like thing, but how can I make a real mesh so that I can fill the hole (see picture). Or maybe there's an option for that.

[image: bezier curve with end open]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the convert to

1. Hit the <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, click on search and key in "convert to"
2. Select Convert to from the search return.
3. Select "Mesh from Curve" from the drop down meun.

Now you have a poly mesh instead of a bezier curve.

Answer (score 21):

Using a Curve Circle as Bevel Object instead the Bevel Option, you'll be able to toggle Fill Caps on.

[image: Fill Caps]

Comment: Thank you so much. A hidden gem. "Fill Caps" is also working with Curve>NurbsCircle. The Add-on "Add Curve: Extra Objects" makes adding a bevel and taper curve super easy with right-click menu. You still have to tick "Fill Caps" because it is off by default. The Add-on "Curve Tools" is also extremely useful. Cheers!